# Trajectories Missing From Phase Plane

Tags: differential-equations

I am attempting to graph trajectories for the system of equations (with independent variable t) given by

x'=5x-3y-2

y'=4x-3y-1

in the phase plane.  For some reason, I can only graph trajectories for half of the points in the window range. My code is below.  Try dragging the locator anywhere in the upper left to see that no solutions appear.  Seems to have something to do with the flow of the trajectories.

```
Manipulate[
 sol = First@
   NDSolve[{x'[t] == 5 x[t] - 3 y[t] - 2, 
     y'[t] == 4 x[t] - 3 y[t] - 1, x[0] == p[[1]], 
     y[0] == p[[2]]}, {x, y}, {t, -20, 50}];
 ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, -20, 20}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotRange -> 5], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

I hope to be able to graph all solutions with the locator.  Some of those missing solutions are shown in the picture below.  I'm pretty new to the NDSolve function, so it may be something simple I am overlooking.  Any ideas?

The StreamPlot function is not suitable for my needs.  So, I'm looking for a solution using NDSolve with ParametricPlot.

[image]

Comment: Your t range is so large that the functions x and y result in  hugh numbers (e.g. 10^30) are generated. If you reduce the t range e.g. to -1 to 1 everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `{t, -20, 20}` with  `{t, -20, 10}`,but I don't know the reason.

```
Manipulate[Module[{sol},
  sol = First@
    NDSolve[{x'[t] == 5 x[t] - 3 y[t] - 2, 
      y'[t] == 4 x[t] - 3 y[t] - 1, {x[0], y[0]} == p}, {x, 
      y}, {t, -20, 50}];
  ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, -20, 10}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   PlotRange -> 5]], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

[image]